# How to remove duplicate from list of values

Tags: python

I have list of dictionary

```
dictio =[{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for subd in dictio:
    for k, v in subd.items():
        result[k].append(v)
result
```

My output

While appending 'value1' appending to 'key1' which is not required

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'key1': ['value1', 'value2', 'value1'],
             'key2': ['value4', 'value5']})
```

My Expected

```
`defaultdict(list,
                {'key1': ['value1', 'value2'],
                 'key2': ['value4', 'value5']})`
```

Comment: In Python `set` collection has only unique values

Comment: This question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-the-lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `list` use `set`

**Ex:**

```
dictio =[{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)
for subd in dictio:
    for k, v in subd.items():
        result[k].add(v)
result
# --> defaultdict(<class 'set'>, {'key1': {'value2', 'value1'}, 'key2': {'value4', 'value5'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn your list of dict into a set and then in a list again, a set would remove all duplicates.

```
dictio = list(set([{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that very simply, just check if the element is already in:

```
dictio =[{'key1':'value1'}, {'key1':'value2'}, {'key1':'value1'}, {'key2':'value4'}, {'key2':'value5'}]
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for subd in dictio:
    for k, v in subd.items():
        if v not in result[k]:
            result[k].append(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this example from https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_howto_remove_duplicates.asp

```
mylist = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c"]
mylist = list(dict.fromkeys(mylist))
print(mylist)
```